# keras.callbacks with TensorBoard is not displaying epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Im working with TensorFlow and the Boston House Prices dataset. When trying to use TensorBoard to display my epochs, I encountered the problem, that there was no output.

I tried to implement it as shown in the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

Im using a google notebook as my environment.

```
%load_ext tensorboard

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime


try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# print(tf.__version__)

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

# clear log from previous runs
!rm -rf ./logs/ 

# Next, we load the data into a 'dataframe' object for easier manipulation, and also print the first few rows in order to examine it
data = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)    
data['MEDV'] = pd.Series(data=boston.target, index=data.index)     

train_dataset = data.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=0)
test_dataset = data.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
train_stats.pop("MEDV")
train_stats = train_stats.transpose()
train_stats

train_labels = train_dataset.pop('MEDV')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('MEDV')

def norm(x):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']
normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset)
normed_test_data = norm(test_dataset)

def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model

model = build_model();

example_batch = normed_train_data[:10]
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)

# Display training progress by printing a single dot for each completed epoch
# not using this for now
class PrintDot(keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
    if epoch % 100 == 0: print('')
    print('.', end='')

EPOCHS = 1000

# Define the Keras TensorBoard callback.
# logdir="logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
# tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)  # this didn't work aswell
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False,
    update_freq='epoch', profile_batch=2, embeddings_freq=0,
    embeddings_metadata=None
)

history = model.fit(
  normed_train_data, train_labels,
  epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
  # callbacks=[PrintDot()])
  callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Output:

```
*nothing*
```

My desired output should look similar to this:

```
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2199 - accuracy: 0.9352 - val_loss: 0.1205 - val_accuracy: 0.9626
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0976 - accuracy: 0.9705 - val_loss: 0.0835 - val_accuracy: 0.9761
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0690 - accuracy: 0.9784 - val_loss: 0.0687 - val_accuracy: 0.9782
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0528 - accuracy: 0.9831 - val_loss: 0.0695 - val_accuracy: 0.9786
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0437 - accuracy: 0.9853 - val_loss: 0.0652 - val_accuracy: 0.9795
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5c3d1ce828>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `verbose=1` in `model.fit()`, it will show data for each epoch.

0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch.